# NSOperationQueue order

Tags: asynchronous, download, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I try create a queue for downloads some file, so I create an NSOperation subclass and then the queue, at the end of the queue I want to send a notification, the problem is that I see into the console the endQueue log before queue is finished.

The log is this:

```
....
Download finished
Download finished
Download finished
Queue finished
Download finished
Download finished
Download finished
...
```

while I need to have

```
....
Download finished
Download finished
Download finished
Download finished
Download finished
Download finished
Queue finished
```

This is my NSOperation subclass

```
- (id) initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setFileDict:dict];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) main {
    [self runOperation];
}

- (void) runOperation {

    NSURL *urlFile = [NSURL URLWithString:[fileDict objectForKey:@"urlStr"];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlFile]
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){

                               if (data) {

                                   [data writeToFile:pathFile atomically:YES];
                                   [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"Download finished" object:nil];
                               }
                           }];
}
```

from another class I create and execute the queue in this way

```
self.operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];;
[self.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

for (NSDictionary *dict in fileDaScaricare) {
    DownloadOperation *downloadOperation = [[DownloadOperation alloc] initWithDictionary:dict];
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:downloadOperation];

}

[self.operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

    NSLog(@"Queue finished");
    [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"endFile" object:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
- (void) runOperation {

NSURL *urlFile = [NSURL URLWithString:[fileDict objectForKey:@"urlStr"];

NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlFile];
    self.downloadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:downloadRequest delegate:self];

    // keeps the NSOperation alive for the during of the NSURLConnection!
    [self.downloadConnection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.downloadConnection start];        
}
```

Then you can observe the notification in NSURLConnectionDelegate methods:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [notificationCenter postNotificationName:@"Download finished" object:nil];
}
```